# streaming gif over a virtual webcam (linux) ffmpeg gif v4l2

Tags: ffmpeg, virtual, gif, webcam, v4l2

i want to stream a gif over ffmpeg to a virtual webcam with v4l2. when i start, the ffmpeg shows a distorted gif.

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=5 card_label=“Virtual cam”

ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i example.gif -vf format=yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video5
```

what could be the problem with the display of the gif, i have also tried different formats (argb, rgb24, yuv420p), but the gif remained distorted! How can i stream/record a gif over a virtual webcam with ffmpeg and v4l2 correctly?

thank you!

Comment: Does "distorted" refer to the size or color or something else?

Comment: hi, thank you for your comment :-)

yes, 'distorted' (maybe blurred is a better word) refer the size (horinzontal strip) and color (defragmented, mainly green)

Comment: Works for me with no issues. Provide a link to the input GIF. Show the complete log from your ffmpeg command. What player are you using to view `/dev/video5`?

Comment: uff, i tested it again, now it runs without problems ... i restart my pc. sorry for absorbing your time :-( but thanks again for your help! :o)